# How to test a method with List<List<T> as input parameter in Xunit

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, xunit, xunit.net

I want to test a method with `List<List<string>>` as parameter. I am using xunit as testing framework.

Here is what I tried.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> CombinationData
{
    get
    {
        return new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string>{ "a", "b", "c" }, 
            new List<string>{ "x", "y", "z" }
        };
    }
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(CombinationData))]
public void CombinationDataTest(List<List<string>> dataStrings)
{
     ...
}
```

I get the following exception when the run the test.

> System.ArgumentException : 
> Property CombinationData on CodeUnitTests.MainCodeTests yielded an item that is not an object[]
>        Stack Trace: at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()

How do I make it work ? Is it the right approach ?

Comment: @RufusL Its the xunit test runner in Visual studio that gives me the exception. (Test output window)

Comment: @RufusL Its not my code that throwing the exception, but the testing framework. The execution is not even hitting a breakpoint inside the test method.

Comment: @RufusL I guess someone can reproduce it with the above code in a test class and put a break point on the starting brace. I am not sure whether it is working for someone else. I can see the testing framework is trying to call the test method by iterating through the **CombinationData** property. It is probably expecting an object[] than a List<>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message is pretty clear. Function provided for `MemberData` should return `IEnumerable<object[]>`, where

- Every item of `IEnumerable` is collection of parameters for one test case
- Every `object` in `object[]` is parameter expected by test method

Your test method expect `List<List<string>>` as parameter so you should return instance of `List<List<string>>` as first item of `object[]`

```
private static IEnumerable<object[]> CombinationData()
{
    var testcase = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string>{ "a", "b", "c" }, 
        new List<string>{ "x", "y", "z" }
    };  
    yield return new object[] { testcase };
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. I was missing one of the fact that you put in the bullets.